# Open and Closed Subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove or disprove each of the following assertions:

(a.) If $A$ is a subset of $\mathbf{R}^d$ such that every subset of $A$ is closed, then $A$ is a finite set (i.e., contains finitely many points).

(b.) If $A$ is a nonempty open subset of $\mathbf{R}^d$, then $A$ contains a nonempty subset that is neither closed nor open.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to approach these.

Answer (score 4):

HINTS:

(a) Consider the set $\Bbb Z$ in $\Bbb R$. More generally, consider the set $\Bbb Z^d$ in $\Bbb R^d$.

(b) Any set of the form $[a,b)$ with $a<b$ is neither open nor closed. This kind of set has a straightforward generalization to higher dimensions.

Comment: (a.)  So every subset of $\mathbf{Z}$ is closed because $\mathbf{Z\setminus R}$ is open?  (b.) So it's okay to use a half open subset of an open interval?

Comment: @user66038: The fact that $\Bbb Z\setminus\Bbb R$ is open just tells you that $\Bbb Z$ is closed, not that every subset of $\Bbb Z$ is closed. However, if $A\subseteq\Bbb Z$, then $$(\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z)\cup\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z\setminus A}\left(n-\frac12,n+\frac12\right)$$ is an open set whose complement is ... what?

Comment: I'm not sure I get it.  Wouldn't the complement of the right hand side be the empty set, if n was large, or is that the point?

Comment: @user66038: What do you mean, ‘if $n$ is large’? There is no fixed quantity $n$ in that expression: $n$ is a dummy variable that ranges over $\Bbb Z\setminus A$. If $A$ is all of $\Bbb Z$ except $0,1$, and $3$, for instance, then $\Bbb Z\setminus A=\{0,1,3\}$, and $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z\setminus A}\left(n-\frac12,n+\frac12\right)$ is $$\left(-\frac12,\frac12\right)\cup\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)\cup\left(\frac52,\frac72\right)\;.$$ The only integers that are in that set are $0,1$, and $3$, so the union of that set and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z$ is everything except $A$.

Comment: I originally read that as $\(-n-1/2, n+1/2\)$, that's why I was confused.  I get this part, but I'm not clear on $\mathbf{Z^d}$.  Is that the coordinates in $\mathbf{R^d}$ that are integers?

Comment: @user66038: Yes: $\Bbb Z^d$ is the set of points in $\Bbb R^d$ all of whose coordinates are integers.

Answer (score 1):

For b) simply remove one point of $A$ andconstruct a sequence of points that accumulate at your omitted point.